# GreenPlum Substring - Getting part of a long text

Tags: postgresql, substring, greenplum

say I have a long URL

```
xyz = 'www.google.com/xyz?para1=value1&para2=value2&para3=value3....'
```

I am trying to get the 'para1' out of this long URL

So, I have

```
select TRIM(Leading '?' from Substring(xyz from '%#"?%=#"%' for '#'))
```

The answer I get for this particular statement is

```
para1=value1&para2=value2&para3=
```

How can I get just 'para1' using the select statement above (or any other similar method?)

I am using Greenplum (as mentioned in the topic heading)

Comment: The pattern expression fails on Pg 9.3, so it's hard for me to test this out. In general, I'd say you want to nest two `substring` expressions, one to cut the front off, another to then chop after the first `=`.

Comment: Hello, thanks :)
I ended up doing it in two steps, once i got everything after the '?', I used the 'Regexp_string_to_table(value &) and then regexp_string_to_table (value =). This way I got all my Paramname (para1,para2...) in one column and Values in the second column.

I tried the two substring, but for some reason, i wasn't able to successfully get the data i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you apparently have the `regexp_` functions (I didn't think Greenplum supported them) use:

```
select (regexp_matches(
   'www.google.com/xyz?para1=value1&para2=value2&para3=value3....',
   '\?([^&]+)='
   ))[1];
```